# I am getting the error while Adding Multiple Records to table using mssql views join

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, join, view

I have 3 or more different table : products , pruducts_features , Pruduct_Prices Etc.

While insert the data , ı got the this error :

View or function 'View_1' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.`

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into View_1 
       (pname,pcount,pprice,pInfo) values(@pname,@pcount,@pprice,@pInfo)"
       , baglanti);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pname",  txt1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pprice", txt2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pprice", txt3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pInfo",  txt4.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`

what am i need to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View can only handle inserts if it is projecting one table - this error message tells clear enough. If you really want to update data in several tables - you should run several sql queries for that, probably in a transaction. If, on the other hand, you want to update just one table - specify its name instead of `View_1` in the query.

Also make sure you specify the whole parameter name, including the `@` symbol:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pname",  txt1.Text);
```

Comment: What do you mean 'in a transaction' ? I could probably use a transaction in my code but I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA, here is what I mean: [SQl transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx) and how to use them in [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I forgot the @ symbol during the writing, i see , could you give me some examples about that  or link ? I cant do it 

also, what is the second alternative way for that ? trigger or store procudure ? which one am i use ?

Comment: @neon, for transactions there are a lot of examples, just google for "ado.net transaction". Here is [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10223/Using-Transactions-in-ADO-NET), for example. In simplest case it just comes down to calling `BeginTransaction` and `Commit` in right places. Stored proc is absolutely a valid alternative.